# Flask, save data from forms to json file

Tags: python, json, flask

I can't figure out how to save data server side. Here is my route:

```
@app.route('/results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def results():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        results = request.form
        return json.dumps(request.form)
```

There I convert the request form from a dictionary to a string. Here is my HTML that makes up the form:

```
<form action = "/results" method = "POST">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Host" name="host" value="host">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Longname" name="longname" value="longname">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Shortname" name="shortname" value="shortname">
                <p><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="send"></p>
```

I made a result page to see if I could convert the form to JSON.
But now I'm stuck, I don't know how to save results to a file. Every time I post the form, I get back something that looks like this:

```
{hosts ["host": "a", "shortname": "c", "longname": "b"], ["host": "a", "shortname": "c", "longname": "b"]}
```

Comment: Do you want to save the form on the server or do you want to offer it as a download for the user/client?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) on the JSON module you'll see that there's a `dump` method that works like `dumps`. You just have to feed it a file object as well:

```
    with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(request.form, f)
    return render_html('your_template.html')
```

That will write out your form to `file.json`. You probably want to set something up in your flask config to store the full path to the file that you plan to save.